# Размер стека во встраиваемых ОС реального времени (FreeRTOS, OpenRtos)

Tags: c, freertos

Пытаюсь использовать FreeRTOS в проекте (проц - avr32). Заметил такую штуку. Если увеличить размер стека для задачи, прошивка тупо виснет. В дизасме пустой бесконечный цикл. Если сделать размер стека задачи маленьким, виснет сама задача. Кто знает, как правильно выбрать размер стека в принципе и какие причины сей проблемы могут быть кроме размера стека?

Answer (score 3):

Виснуть может по простой причине - процессор просто не может выделить сколько места под стек. Пусть у Вас всего 32кб памяти, а под стек выделяете 64кб - понятно, что будут пробемы:)
С другой стороны, 16кб может быть нормально, но в памяти не только стек размещается... Но обычно стек больше половины доступной оперативки не должен быть.

Также, нужно помнить, что эти процессоры очень привередливы. Например, размер стека должен быть кратным 4кб. Иначе виснет. Все это лучше читать в документации на процессор.

И ещё одна причина подвисания прошивок, с которой я стыкался. У некоторых процессоров flash для прошивки не монолитный, а составной, например 8+8+16+32кб, то есть, 4 блока разного размера. И если какая то процедура попадает на стык - могут быть проблемы. А если ещё код выполняет близкий переход через границу - так подвисает на ура. Решалось анализом кода и составленим правильно мап файла для распределения процедур по блокам.

Comment: По поводу места под стек - его явно достаточно. ОЗУ 128Кб, стек выделяю ~1Кб на задачу. В задаче нет ничего памятиемкого. Бывает чудом все работает, добавишь инструкцию типа инкремента и копец. В дизасме строчка с переходом на саму себя. А как может кратность 4Кб влиять? Стек же чисто программный. Интересно.

Comment: В АВР память же линейно расположена? Не составная? Или не всегда так? А по поводу мап можно подробнее?

Comment: о кратности 4к - эта цифра взята с головы. Просто некоторые процессоры хотят строго определенного размера.
>> В дизасме строчка с переходом на саму себя.
а вот это уже весело. Это немного объясняет. Ваш код на асме сразу пишется или на С?
>>  АВР память же линейно расположена? Не составная?
на эти вопросы ответит документация.

Comment: `Ваш код на асме сразу пишется или на С?`

Пишется на С. Компилятор GCC.

Comment: раз код пишется на С, а в результирующем коде бесконечные циклы - то это два варианта
- глюк компилятора
- нужно посмотреть, как происходит переход на эту строку с бесконечным циклом. Возможно, где то делается к примеру короткий переход через границу, но это не получится и будет осуществлен переход в свой же блок.
Распечатать блок можно командой -Map mapfile и посмотреть, как компилятор с линковщиком все разместили.